# MongoDB and Birt or JasperReports, hierarchical data

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports, birt

In the current BIRT Release (4.3.0) (and JasperReports iReport 5.1.0) there is now a MongoDB db Connection possible.
One question would be on how you could iterate over hierarchical data.

I have a dataset d like

```
d-p1
 -p2
 -p3
 -c1[]
 -c1[].Name
 -c1[].xxx
```

How could I show p1 in the report an have a table of items contained in the c1[] collection of the current dataset?